# Set Attribute OnClick of a UserControl

Tags: asp.net

I am using a third party control which not shows any onclick event option, since its a user control how can i add onclick event to it?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

```
serverControl.Attributes.Add("onclick", "yourMethod()");
```

should do the trick

though the control might explicitly block you from doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee this will work on the control you're using, but certainly for the standard ASP.NET controls, you can just add it to the markup. You'll get a little squiggle under it, but just ignore that and it will make it into the final markup:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" onclick="alert('hi!');"/>
```

Comment: Thanx Graham, but there is no option of 'OnClick' for panel

Comment: @BreakHead: yes, Visual Studio will complain and tell you it doesn't exist, but just put it in there anyway and it *will* get rendered out.